# How to create a textbox that accepts input and displays any valid query that is in my database in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
$res = $conn->query($query);

echo("<b>Employee</b><br><br>");

if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $row['empID']
                . "</td><td>" . $row['empFirstName']
                . "</td><td>" . $row['empLastName']
                . "</td><td>" . $row['empDept']
                . "</td><td>" . $row['empPhone']
                . "</td><td>" . $row['empEmail']
                . "</td><td>" . $row['empAddress']
                . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
} else {
        echo "0 result";
}

/* close connection */
$conn->close();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is currently how each table is setup. As of right now, each table is a separate link on the homepage. At the bottom of the home page, there is a textbox with a submit and clear button. My issue is, how exactly do I go about typing in any query I desire and have it return the results of the query submitted?

Updated 8:17PM:
Textbox portion of homepage.

```
<b>Ad-hoc Query:</b><br><br>

<form action="querybox.php" method="post">
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td align = right>
              <strong>Please enter your query here<br></font></strong>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type=text size=130 maxlength=280 name="query">
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td align = right>
              <input type=reset value="Clear">
           </td>
           <td>
              <input type=submit value="Submit">
           </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You want to submit the query in the text box?

Comment: @Dula correct. The text box is already made i just don't know how to go from here.

Comment: the database is being pulled from myphpadmin

Comment: It is not recommended to submit queries using text boxes or any other input method because anyone can submit any kind of query into your database. It is a major security risk!!!

Comment: @Dula i get that, its just for a class project and those are the teachers requirements so I have no choice

Comment: ok..can you post the code for the text box and other codes.

Comment: @Dula just updated my post. I just need to edit the querybox.php file to work with this and I'm also not sure how to dynamically make the tables. Static tables are fairly easy and I haven't had a problem with those yet.